# How do I run a stress test to get the TPS of the Hedera local network?

Tags: hedera-hashgraph

I have deployed the private Hedera local network on my machine and want to test its transactions per second (TPS).

Are there any tools or tutorials available for performance testing the TPS of the Hedera local network system?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question (about local network, and peak tx/s), but for the public networks and average tx/s, you can use this method:
https://hedera.com/blog/hedera-processes-thousands-of-tps-see-how-that-number-is-calculated